# Wordpress - Something Mysteriously Adding a <br> after body tag

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have a wordpress site where there is a `<br>` appearing right after the first body tag that's causing the entire site to have a line space at the top of the page.

I manually looked at the header.php code and there is nothing between the body tag and the opening Google Tag Manager comment.  When loading the site, however, something is inserting application/ld+json script code for SEO and I'm assuming along with the `<br>`, so my suspicion is it's caused by the Yoast SEO plugin.  I'm trying to look at the plugin files for code where it's inserting this script code, but I can't seem to find anything.

This is what the header.php code looks like when editting it in the Wordpress editor:
[image]

This is what the header.php code looks like after loading the Wordpress site in a browser:
[image]

Does anyone have any clue why or where the 
 is being inserted from?

Thanks!

Comment: is the `br` tag also inserted if you deactivate the yoast plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Just as I posted this question, I found the ld+json script code above the body tag code in header.php that had a `<br/>` before it.  I removed it and it fixed the issue.